# Why does RecyclerView.getChildAt(i) and Recycler.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i) returns different views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have an horizontal recyclerView that contains 3 items. 
I add to my recyclerView one item at position 1 so now I have a recyclerView with 4 items.

When I call RecyclerView.getChildAt(1) it returns the view at position 0 instead of 1.

When I call RecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(1) it returns the view at position 1.

why does it happen? Is it any way to reset the indexes so when I'll call RecyclerView.getChildAt(1) it will return the item at index 1 and not the item at position 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefully.

RecyclerView.getChildAt(1) refers to ViewGroup.getChildAt()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)

RecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(1) has a different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView.getChildAt(int position) get the childView at **Visible Area**, for example, the screen can hold three itemViews, if you call RecyclerView.getChildAt(2), what returns is the second view of visible area,but is not the second view of the adapter, only calling layoutManager.getChildAt(2) can return the view at position 2.